# Add Select Option in converted UL list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script to convert a UL to a select drop down box:

```
$(function() {
$('ul.cat-nav').each(function() {
    var $select = $('<select id="category" />');
    $(this).find('a').each(function() {
        var $option = $('<option />');
        $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
        $select.append($option);
    });
    $(this).replaceWith($select);
    });
});
```

This works great, but I would like to add an initial option of "Choose One" as the first option. When I add this code to the above, it does not add the initial option:

```
$("#category").html("<option value='#'>Choose One</option>");
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try the `prepend` method. http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add the "Choose One" `<option>` before you add the rest of the options.

Change your code to include the added line:

```
$(function() {
$('ul.cat-nav').each(function() {
    var $select = $('<select id="category" />');

    $select.append("<option value='#'>Choose One</option>");

    $(this).find('a').each(function() {
        var $option = $('<option />');
        $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
        $select.append($option);
    });
    $(this).replaceWith($select);
    });
});
```

[See this jsfiddle for example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhKWr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$("#category").prepend("<option value='#'>Choose One</option>");
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when the `<ul>` gets replaced with the `<select>`, the browser automatically selects the first `<option>`. Later, the "Choose One" option is added, but the browser doesn't switch to it automatically.

Comment: @Travis In that case you can select the first option manually `$('#category option:first').prop('selected', true)`

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
var $select = $('<select id="category" />');
```

with

```
var $select = $('<select id="category"><option value="#">Choose One</option></select>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Pedro is indeed correct, just to add the reason why which is that you need to use a different JQuery method.

.html() will replace the contents of the HTML object selected whereas .prepened() will add data before the item selected (which is what you want).

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/